# Mongoose populate virtual возвращает массив из одного объекта, а должен - один объект

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Метод populate для virtual возвращает массив из одного объекта, а хотелось бы получить сам объект, не в массиве

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
})

let postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String, // ссылка на объект юзера
  message: String
})

postSchema.virtual('author', {
  ref: 'user',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: '_id'
})

postSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
postSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })

let User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'test_users')
let Post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema, 'test_posts')

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {

  Post.findOne()
    .populate('author')
    .exec()
    .then(post => {

      /*
        в post возвращает следующий объект
        author - объект в массиве, а нужно получить просто объект
        {
          "_id": "5c9cd63348b17b086c0c3c7a",
          "userId": "5c9cd5fdaaf7c82ba47d0709",
          "message": "Hello world",
          "__v": 0,
          "author": [
            {
              "_id": "5c9cd5fdaaf7c82ba47d0709",
              "firstName": "Harry",
              "lastName": "Potter",
              "__v": 0
            }
          ],
          "id": "5c9cd63348b17b086c0c3c7a"
        }
      */

    })
})
```

Я знаю, что можно использовать populate для userId, тогда объект попадет прямо в поле userId, но нужно добавить объект именно в поле author

Answer (score 0):

Долго гуглил, но по закону подлости нашел ответ сразу как задал вопрос
Нужно добавить параметр `justOne: true` при объявлении `virtual`

```
postSchema.virtual('author', {
  ref: 'user',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true
})
```